# Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Errors::AccessDeniedException

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

**Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Errors::AccessDeniedException**

I using AWS ElasticTranscoder service to create job and convert videos.

I getting below error on creating AWS ElasticTranscoder job.

> Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Errors::AccessDeniedException (User:
>   arn:aws:iam::119945600465:user/s3_bucket_user is not authorized to
>   perform: elastictranscoder:CreateJob on resource:
>   arn:aws:elastictranscoder:us-east-1:119945600465:pipeline/1464161888836-rawwl7)

log file:

```
I, [2018-06-22T11:43:22.942346 #17751]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 100560ms (ActiveRecord: 29.3ms)
F, [2018-06-22T11:43:22.942944 #17751] FATAL -- :   
F, [2018-06-22T11:43:22.942988 #17751] FATAL -- : Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Errors::AccessDeniedException (User: arn:aws:iam::119945600465:user/s3_bucket_user is not authorized to perform: elastictranscoder:CreateJob on resource: arn:aws:elastictranscoder:us-east-1:119945600465:pipeline/1464161888836-rawwl7):
F, [2018-06-22T11:43:22.943032 #17751] FATAL -- :   
F, [2018-06-22T11:43:22.943081 #17751] FATAL -- : app/services/aws/upstge/transcode_video.rb:42:in `create_job'
app/services/aws/upstge/transcode_video.rb:11:in `call'
app/jobs/aws/upstge/video_preview_transcoder.rb:9:in `perform'
app/controllers/video_editors_controller.rb:38:in `create'
```

transcode_video.rb file:

```
module Aws
  module Name
    class TranscodeVideo
      def initialize(video, job_response: nil)
        @video = video
        @job_response = job_response
      end

      def call
        resolutions = collect_resolutions
        create_job resolutions
      end

      private

      def collect_resolutions
        logger = Logger.new('log/aws_job.log')

        if @job_response.blank?
          Array(wallet[:transcoder][:stage_zero_mode])
        else
          wallet[:transcoder][:modes][:keys].tap { |keys| keys.delete(wallet[:transcoder][:stage_zero_mode]) }
          .delete_if { |res| res.to_i > max_resolution }
        end
      end

      def create_job(resolutions)
        logger = Logger.new('log/aws_job.log')
        return :no_available_resolutions if resolutions.blank?

        resolutions.each do |res|
          mode = wallet[:transcoder][:modes][:"360p"]
          logger.info "------------- mode ----------"
          logger.info mode
          options[:outputs].push({ key: "#{mode[:prefix]}/#{'51507dd0-aa55-42d4-8e89-33264f24bf1d'}#{mode[:extension]}",
                                   thumbnail_pattern: "#{mode[:prefix]}/#{'51507dd0-aa55-42d4-8e89-33264f24bf1d'}---{count}",
                                   preset_id: mode[:preset] })

        end
        logger.info "-----------------------"
        logger.info options
        transcoder.create_job(options)
        :started
      end

      def options
        @options ||= { pipeline_id: wallet[:transcoder][:pipeline],
                       input: { key: s3_object },
                       outputs: [] }
      end

      def s3_object
        @video.s3_object
      end

      def wallet
        @wallet ||= Rails.application.secrets.aws
      end

      def transcoder
        @transcoder ||= Aws::ElasticTranscoder::Client.new access_key_id: wallet[:access_key_id],
                                                           secret_access_key: wallet[:secret_access_key],
                                                           region: wallet[:region]
      end

      def max_resolution
        @max_resolution ||= (
          response = transcoder.read_job(id: @job_response.job_id)
          response.job.input.detected_properties.height
        )
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: And what is your question? What permissions have been assigned to the IAM user called _s3_bucket_user_?

Comment: AmazonS3FullAccess permissions to s3_bucket_user

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says:

```
s3_bucket_user is not authorized to perform: elastictranscoder:CreateJob
```

Your *s3_bucket_user* only has permissions to use Amazon S3. The error message says that your code is attempting to call the `CreateJob()` command on Elastic Transcoder. Therefore, the *s3_bucket_user* requires `elastictranscoder:CreateJob` permissions.

If you want to do it easily, simply give them the `AmazonElasticTranscoder_JobsSubmitter` policy, or another one you deem appropriate.